# Display value an index represents on the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have code which makes a plot of a two-dimensional array. Along the x-axis is just the index of my array, but I would like the x-axis to display the value that index represents.

Relevant code:

```
plt.imshow(data, aspect="auto")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Where "data" is a 1000 by 200 array. So at the moment, the plot is created correctly, and the x-axis shows the index number of array (0-199).

But this index also corresponds to a date in another list that I have (date[]) of length 200. I want the date corresponding to the index to show on the x-axis, and not the index itself.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put the x-ticks and the labels you can use

```
plt.xticks(range(200),date)
```

However the above will put too many ticks and labels. If you want to reduce the number of ticks to say 5, you can use

```
idx=np.linspace(0,199,5).astype('int')
plt.xticks(idx,[date[i] for i in idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write the imshow() method, or is that part of a library? 
If it's yours, just add a line that takes the date[x] value for each x.

If that method is part of a library, you maybe be able to finagle something else, though I'd need to know more about it.

Comment: I don't really understand what it means to"write the imshow() method", so I guess that means that I didn't write it. But yes, what you said is something like what I need to do. Would I need to post the rest of my code? It's quite messy as I am a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "did you create the imshow() method yourself or are you using one that already existed". It looks like imsc is more knowledgeable about this than I am though, take a look at his answer.